# How would I make a custom pickaxe in forge for 1.16.5?

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

So I want to make a custom pickaxe in forge moding for 1.16.5.

I have tried this:

```
package io.github.yamiatem.fiery_stuff.core.item;

import io.github.yamiatem.fiery_stuff.FieryStuff;
import net.minecraft.item.Item;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemGroup;
import net.minecraft.item.PickaxeItem;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.RegistryObject;
import net.minecraftforge.registries.DeferredRegister;
import net.minecraftforge.registries.ForgeRegistries;

public class ItemInit {
    public static final DeferredRegister<Item> ITEMS = DeferredRegister.create(ForgeRegistries.ITEMS, FieryStuff.MOD_ID);

    public static final RegistryObject<Item> FIERY_INGOT = ITEMS.register("fiery_ingot", () -> new Item(new Item.Properties().group(ItemGroup.MISC)));
    
    public static final RegistryObject<PickaxeItem> FIERY_PICK = ITEMS.register("fiery_pick", new PickaxeItem(null, 0, 0, null));
}
```

But I want to create a custom pickaxe from scratch with custom durability, efficiency, and tier and stuff like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing null to arguments of PickaxeItem you need to pass some valid values.
IItemTier is determine characteristics of tool.

```java
public class CustomTier implements IItemTier {
    @Override public int   getMaxUses()             { return 1000;}
    @Override public float getEfficiency()          { return 10; }
    @Override public float getAttackDamage()        { return 10; }
    @Override public int   getHarvestLevel()        { return 3; }
    @Override public int   getEnchantability()      { return 5; }
    @Override public Ingredient getRepairMaterial() { return Ingredient.fromStacks(new ItemStack(FIERY_INGOT.get())); }
}
```

```java
public static final RegistryObject<PickaxeItem> FIERY_PICK = ITEMS.register("fiery_pick", 
    new PickaxeItem(new CustomTier(), 0, 0, new Properties().maxStackSize(1)));
```

Look class ItemTier for vanilla tiers.

Comment: Okay, I have a few questions. What does getEnchantability() mean? Also, would I create this class in a different file of the same one? Also, does getEfficiency() set the tier value like netherite pickaxe has tier 4 so would this one have tier 10?@hohserg

Comment: Enchantability is a characteristic of tool materials which determine quality of random enchants at enchanting table. Look ItemTier for values of vanilla tiers